# TextView above ImageView: Space between the top of the scaled SVG and the bottom of the TextView is scaled

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

In my application, a `TextView` is shown above an `ImageView` which contains a SVG image. Depending on the screen resolution, the `ImageView`, which is constrained (top and bottom *e.g.*) by another `ImageView`, is scaled: thus its SVG is also scaled by decreasing its height (and width, proportionnaly). Thus, the space between the `TextView` and the `ImageView` is technically the same than the one in Android Studio but is visually longer.

What I would want is: to keep the same space in Android Studio than on all screen resolutions, *i.e.*: 8dp.

**Example:**

In the Android Studio's visualizator, the space is 8dp:

[image]

In a Samsung Galaxy S7, I think the space is still 8dp but the SVG has been scaled: the space seems longer.

[image]

Proof that the SVG is scaled and that the `ImageView` is really at 8dp from the `TextView`:

[image]

Do you know how to keep the same space than in Android Studio, whatever the screen resolution?

## Warning

I really want the SVG to be scaled (so I don't want, *e.g.* to set `scale: fitXY` or something like that). But I also want the space between the bottom of the `TextView` and the top of the scaled SVG be 8dp on all screen resolutions.

Comment: Create a vertical chain with ImageView and TextView or you can use Barrier.

Comment: Creating a vertical layout would result on the same problem no?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but I think that your image is causing the problem.

As you said - your space is the same 8dp all the time but because your image has a white background, when you use a bigger image the white background scales and it looks like the space between your text and image is larger.

You can use some view with non-white background and scale it for testing - I believe that you will see the same spacing regards the view size. If this will be the case maybe try to change your image.

Comment: The image is a SVG with transparent background. Yes the `ImageView` is always 8dp, I'm sure since I just have set a background color to the `ImageView` and this background color is present just below the `TextView`. So the SVG is just scaled, and the top of the SVG is "far" below the top of its `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout layout with constraints to ensure a fixed proportion no matter what
E.g

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/main_layout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"

>
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="40"
      />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="60"

       />

 </LinearLayout>
```

So no matter what, in our example, the image will always be 40% of the horizontal space while the text will be 60%. I believe you can apply this idea to your situation

Comment: Even with a (vertical not horizontal) `LinearLayout` and the use of the weight concept, the SVG would be scaled no? Thus the problem won't be solved.